# Having xwin start by default on system boot

Tags: debian, gnome, xorg, x11

My system boots into a console, from which I can launch my gnome desktop by issuing the command `startx`. How can `X` be instructed to start by default upon boot? The commands `/etc/init.d/gdm3 start` and `/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=75363&p=417945#p417945), a solution is

```
apt-get remove --purge gdm3
aptitude install gdm3
```

Comment: `apt-get purge gdm3` should also work, but I don't know since which version

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands below.

```
update-rc.d -f gdm3 remove
update-rc.d gdm3 defaults
```

Comment: Thanks, @patrician. I tried that, but it did not resolve the problem.